# MySQL SELECT IF differentiate SUM

Tags: mysql, if-statement, select

My database structure looks as follows:

```
id    |    valuefor   |    quantity
1          alpha           500
2          alpha           100
3          beta            200
```

I am using following mysql command

```
SELECT IF(valuefor=alpha, SUM(quantity),0) as alpha
     , IF(valuefor=beta, SUM(quantity),0) as beta 
  FROM mytable
```

Current Output:

```
alpha   |   beta
800         0
```

The obvious issue with the above is that it SUMS all the rows since I have used SUM. How can I overcome this dilemma? I want to get quantity of alpha and beta separately.

Secondly I am confused as to why did the beta not have value=800 in the output and why does it say 0. This is just for my better understanding of the issue.

I want to result to look something as follows:

```
alpha    |    beta
600           200
```

Comment: That's not a dilemma.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN valuefor=alpha THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS alpha,
       SUM(CASE WHEN valuefor=beta THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS beta
FROM mytable
```

Comment: Ok wow that was simply amazing. Thank you so much!  And here I thought that it wasn't possible. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `case` statement for that like so:

```
select
  sum(case valuefor when 'alpha' then quantity else 0 end) as alpha,
  sum(case valuefor when 'beta' then quantity else 0 end) as beta
from test;
```

**Example:**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f07bbf

```
create table test (
  id int,
  valuefor varchar(20),
  quantity int
);

insert into test values
(1, 'alpha', 500),
(2, 'alpha', 100),
(3, 'beta', 200);
```

**Result**

```
| alpha | beta |
|-------|------|
|   600 |  200 |
```

Comment: Dang, Giorgos already answered this question full 2 minutes ago! Well, I'll keep this answer in case someone wants to use the fiddle.